# Upper and lower limits of events

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

$(S,\Sigma)$ is a measurable space. $\{A_n\}\subset \Sigma$ is a sequence of events. I want to prove that
$$\limsup_n A_n \setminus \liminf_n A_n=\limsup_n (A_n\cap A_{n+1}^c)=\limsup_n (A_n^c\cap A_{n+1}).$$

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Your MathJax code was immensely more complicated than necessary.  I changed \underset{n}{\lim \sup} to \limsup_n. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\in\limsup A_n$ if and only if the set $N_x:=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid x\in A_n\}$ is infinite.

$x\in\liminf A_n$ if and only if the set $M_x:=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid x\notin A_n\}$ is finite.

So $x\in\limsup A_n\setminus\liminf A_n$ is the statement that $N_x$ and $M_x$ are both infinite.

If that is the case then you can find a strictly increasing sequence $(n_k)_k$ with $x\in A_{n_k}\cap A_{n_k+1}^c$ for each $k$.

This proves that $K_x:=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid x\in A_n\cap A_{n+1}^c\}$ is infinite, wich means the same as $x\in\limsup A_n\cap A_{n+1}^c$.

Conversely if $K_x$ is infinite then it follows directly that $N_x$ and $M_x$ are infinite.

Likewise you can reason when it concerns $\limsup A_n^c\cap A_{n+1}$.